# Mark all emails as read locally

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is there anyway to mark all emails as read, but only locally?

I have a lot of emails in my email, that are unread (newsletter etc). I want the new mail icon to disappear once I have checked the folder (so without opening the email itself), just when I have looked at the preview. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Only locally doesn't sound good. You are trying to disable one of the best features of Outlook. Ideally it should sync so that you can work from any device. If you disable sync, you will not get new mails too.
2. To mark all mails from a folder as read, right click on folder & select `Mark All as Read`.

Comment: I still want it to sync, but on my computer only, I want it so that as soon as I make outlook active, any email which I see on my screen will be counted as read, but on the server side, it'll still be unread.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if there is a way to do so and even if it is there, it is not a proper practice. Synchronisation of mails works when you access it from any device. If you want to mark all the mails as read, then just Click on the 'More' Link and click on 'Mark all as read'. This should serve the purpose

Comment: Yea I want that to only be locally, not on the serverside. :\